# File display error C

Tags: c, text-files

I am trying to display a file with in the command prompt window, but the problem is that the output has random 0s in it, however, it always has the right formatting and right amount of rows and spaces. The problem is not the file. If you have any ideas, I'll greatly appreacite it. I have no leads at the moment.

```
void one (void)
{
    FILE *fptr;

    fptr = fopen("C:\z.txt","r+");

    int j, h;

    printf("How many elements?");
    scanf("%d",&h);
    if (fptr==NULL)
    {
     printf("Error!");
      exit(1);
    }
    //fread(a, sizeof(struct book),1,fptr);
    for (j = 0 ; j < h ; j++)
    {
        //fprintf(stdout, "%s\t%s\t%s\t%.2f\t%.2f\t%.2f\t%d\t%d\t%.2f\t\n",a[j].company,a[j].model,a[j].colour,a[j].cost,a[j].price,a[j].value,a[j].stock,a[j].sold,a[j].profit);
        fscanf(fptr,"%s\t%s\t%s\t%.2f\t%.2f\t%.2f\t%d\t%d\t%.2f\t\n",
            a[j].company,
            a[j].model,
            a[j].colour,
            &a[j].cost,
            &a[j].price,
            &a[j].value,
            &a[j].stock,
            &a[j].sold,
            &a[j].profit
        );
    }
    fclose(fptr);
    //getch();
    for (j = 0 ; j < h ; j++)
    {
        printf("%s\t%s\t%s\t%.2f\t%.2f\t%.2f\t%d\t%d\t%.2f\t\n",
            a[j].company,
            a[j].model,
            a[j].colour,
            a[j].cost,
            a[j].price,
            a[j].value,
            a[j].stock,
            a[j].sold,
            a[j].profit
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please write readable code? even for yourself?

Comment: I see one error in it at the start, `ender code here` is not commented

Comment: You never check if the file opened, big mistake, most importantly, you ignore `fscanf()`'s return value, please take the time to read about how every function works, there is a return value for it, do not ignore it and assume that every thing just works, because most of the time, things don't work.

Comment: It's pretty bad form to ask for help when you haven't even bothered to check for the errors that your library functions will tell you about.